# Merging Multiple RSS feeds

Tags: asp.net, rss

I’m very new to programming with RSS feeds to please forgive me if this sounds like a really general question.

Is it possible to take multiple RSS feeds from multiple sites and combine them as a single object to show to the end user?

For example, could I take the latest news headlines from one site, the latest blog updates from a totally different site  and combine them into a single list to show the user?

I have seen this sort of question asked before and it seems like its possible, but the slight twist is I want to let the user add any feed that they want from any source

I’m looking to do this in ASP.NET

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`SyndicationFeed` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) to work with RSS feeds in .Net.

You probably want to do something like this (untested):

```
var allItems = new List<SyndicationItem>();

foreach(var feedUrl in whatever) { //In your list of urls
    using(var reader = XmlReader.Create(url))
        allItems.AddRange(SyndicationFeed.Load(reader).Items);
}

var newFeed = new SyndicationFeed(items);

//Do something with newFeed
```

You should add error handling in case one of the feeds is unavailable or invalid.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, yes.

For a good example of this kind of thing in action, check out [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com).

This would probably be a good application of LINQ to XML, but I'll leave the implementation up to you.